# IOS Notifications not launching under certain condition

Tags: ios

I am using notifications to run certain methods on the user's IOS devices. These instructions are under the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
```

method. However I notice that if the app is running and in foreground in that moment, the method is called. If it is in the background and opened through the notification in the notification center it is called, but if opened through the app icon and not through the notification, it is not. Is there a way to make so that it is always called?

P.S. I'm using IOS8

Comment: If you badge the icon you can read `applicationIconBadgeNumber` of `UIApplication`.

Comment: @Desdenova I hope I haven't misunderstood your answer, but what I am trying to do here is to have a method callback, not read the application icon badge number

Comment: I don't think you can. But you can read the badge number when the application become active to see if you received any notifications.